# Swift Select all text of a UITextfield from UITableviewCell Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to select ALL text in a `UITextField` i.e. inside a `UITableviewCell`. But every Solution i find here wont work. It never selects the text of the `UITextfield` I tapped into.

Here is me Code (simplified). Does anyone know where the problem could be?

```
class generalTextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func textFieldDidBeginEditing(sender: UITextField) {
         sender.becomeFirstResponder()
         sender.delegate = self.textField.delegate
         sender.selectAll(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the delegate of `textField` with current `ViewController` and try to use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method of `UITextField`.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.selectAll(nil)
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to set the `textField` delegate inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this `cell.textField.delegate = self`